# Android Change listview items from another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-fragmentactivity

I am new on Android Fragments, I want to ask, how can we update Listview items which is in FragmentActivity from other Fragment.
Thanks

Comment: use interfacing between the two by the use of interface and update using that interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the reference to your activity in your fragment, and call a function there that will do the update.

```
//In Activity 
private void updateListView(Foo foo...){
    //ToDo update ListView
}

//In Fragment
((MyActivity) getActivity()).updateListView(Foo foo...);
```

The above method is the easiest.  But if you are wondering what the other options are:

- create an interface, and have your activity implement the interface. You'll cast getActivity to your interface instead.  Why we'd do this?  If you wanted to use the fragment with other activities.
- use a LocalBroadcastManager.  Why we'd do this? If we had multiple components (e.g. activity / other fragments) that needed to receive the same data/update.